# CSS Bootstrap container background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and I was wondering what would be a clean way to give a background to my container.

I am using the bootstrap class `container`, not `container-fluid`. Bootstrap doc clearly states that I shouldn't nest containers, so what is the alternative to achieve this goal ? If I set a background to my `container` the left and right margins are still white, I want to colour that space as well, but I also want my content to be aligned the way the `container` is aligned, not the way the `container-fluid` is aligned. Any suggestions ? My current solution is nesting a `container` inside `container-fluid` and remove the padding from the first one, but I want to make a better solution that doesn't go against the bootstrap documentation.

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT**

Here is for example what I had

```
<div class="container-fluid my-class">
    <div class="container">
        Some rows and columns here
    </div>
</div>
```

and then I override bootstrap's padding in css

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.my-class {
    background: red;
}
```

But, like I said, this is the bad way to do it.

Comment: Show the code what you did till now. How much you implemented.

Comment: I updated my question to show my structure

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Bootstrap doc clearly states that I shouldn't nest containers` **under other containers** so just nest your container div under a new class div say, `container-bg` and add the background-image to that div like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- your content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container-bg {
    background: xxx;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so simple indeed, now I am questioning myself why I was bothering so much to do it with bootstrap classes. Little typo: you named the class differently in css

Comment: this is obsolete. use `bg-<color>`

Comment: @MaxMuster Been a while since I last used Bootstrap tbh. Does `<color>` accept any parameter (equal to `xyz` rgb/hex/etc code) or are there only a pre-defined group of colours you have to choose from?

Comment: @AndrewL64 as usual in bootstrap you can define variables, make use of the sass functionality or use the standard primary secondary success danger warning info light dark body white transparent ...

Comment: @MaxMuster Not everyone uses SASS and the default colors (primary, secondary, success, danger, warning, etc) might not be what people are looking for or they are looking for a specific color that matches their theme.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the background for the whole page, then set it on `body`.

If you want to set it for a section of the page, then wrap that section in an appropriate element (such as `div` or `section`), add a class, id or some other way to target it with a selector … just *not one that uses a class provided by Bootstrap*.

Answer (score 2):

**For Boostrap V4.0 and later**

If you want to use boostrap colors as background, you can use [these colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color) for the background, like below example

```
<div class="container bg-dark">
    <!-- your content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add background color to the container you can add the style as inline css like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid my-class style="background-color: green;">
<div class="container">
    Some rows and columns here
</div>
</div>
```